# Make Object available to all methods c++

Tags: c++

Can anyone help me with this? basically I have a test class, wihtin this test class I have a number of methods which all use the same type of setup. Let me show you by example:

```
class Test:public CxxTest::TestSuite
{
  public:

  void Test1(){/*...*/}
  void Test2(){/*...*/}
};
```

Each test method requires the same type of setup:

```
Class c_objectName = AnotherClass::method("c_name","c_name","c_name");
class c_newObjectName = AnotherCLass::create(c_objectName);
```

I am currently setting this in every single method, because each of the above i started with "c_..." needs to be different.

I tried to make a "global method" that would take in a string to rename these each time, but then I cant seems to access them from the method calls. I tried the following:

```
class Test:public CxxTest::TestSuite
{
  public:
  void method()
  {    Class c_objectName = AnotherClass::method("c_name","c_name","c_name");    <--- cant access these 
       Class c_newObjectName = AnotherClass::create(c_objectName);
  }
  void Test1(){/*...*/}
  void Test2(){/*...*/}
};
```

Is there a way to put this in a "global method" of some sort so that I can access these from the methods?

Im really bad at explaining things so sorry and thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean, "can't access these"?   What errors are you getting?

Comment: Unless I missed something it sounds like you're looking for "member variables".

Comment: What is 'Class'?  You don't create objects in C++ with 'new' unless you are using pointers.

Answer (score 1):

I can't make heads and tails of the question, but it looks like something like this would help:

```
 struct TestFixture
 {
      Class c_objectName;
      Class c_newObjectName;
 };

 TestFixture makeFixture()
 {
     TestFixture fixture; 
     fixture.c_objectName = new Class("c_name","c_name","c_name");
     fixture.c_newObjectName = create(c_objectName);
     return fixture;
 }
```

<sub>(assuming your Class (classes?) are copyable. If not, return a pointer to a new instance of TestFixture or something like scoped_ptr</sub>

Then you could use it in your test methods:

```
 void Test1()
 {
      TestFixture fixture = makeFixture();
      // use fixture.c_objectName etc.
```

If you don't mind sharing the data, you could just make them fields of class Test.

**Edit** *Oh, I just realized you are using CxxTest*, [which probably has a better way of creating fixtures/setup/teardown for unit tests](http://cxxtest.sourceforge.net/guide.html#TOC25). However, the above approach should work in any framework.

Comment: You are right I am using Cxx but I still dont know how to make it properly, also I didnt mean to write "new" I was just trying to show a rough sketch I have edited above to show this